# Write Label in ASP from C# on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I am trying to write an asp label from C# and when I run the project in debug it's working but when I deploy it on server the button seems to lose something and this don't work.

my label is created like this:

```html
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblErr" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
```

and on the C# I have the following code:

```cs
try
{
    lblErr.Text = "Botão " + btnValidar.Text;
    lblErr.Text = "Antes de preencher o template.";

    if (ligacoes.PreencheTemplate(dados))
    {
        lblErr.Text += " Template Preenchido.";
    }
    else
    {
        lblErr.Text += " Erro a preencher Template.";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblErr.Text = "Excepção: " + ex.Message;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Kind Regards

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It doesn't give any error. Simply doesn't write anything. I started by trying to write a log but when it started to don't write anything, I tryed to write a label with some messages. Can it be something to do with some permissions on the server, or something on IIS?

Comment: Where is that code located? Page_Load?

Comment: It's on a button click '''protected void btnValidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) '''

Comment: so the click may not working - check for javascript errors - did you see of post back is made ? do you see the source of the page to see if there are text there that you can not read because of html errors ?

Comment: I also thought that, @Aristos but the other actions that i have inside the button click are working, like filling text boxes on the screen from the data collected in the database. Only after doing this collection of data and filling the textboxes, I am doing the code supplied above.

Comment: @FilipeVilhena Check for errors on EventLog if you can. Or check for javascript errors, and see the source of html of the page

Comment: No errors on EventLog and also no errors on javascript or HTML...